Unable to solve "Option id 'null' is not valid" error - Java Jira API
<Edited to remove typo's and make it clear>
I have browsed extensively on this error, and people either say that the field name is wrong or the field value is wrong in their cases but I have tried all possible combinations to no avail.
I am using Java API for JIRA to create a new bug, and my company has a field called "Detected by Test Type" (customfield_15870). The accepted values are "Integration Testing", "Functional Testing" and "Performance Testing". Each look like this (I did a getField on this field from an existing bug and got individual values)
value: "Performance Testing"
id: "12345"
self: "https:///rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12345"
disabled: false
This tells me I got the field name correct, and the individual values correct too.
Here is my code:
Map<String, Object> cascadingValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
cascadingvalues.put("value",  "Performance Testing");
cascadingvalues.put("id",  "12345");
cascadingvalues.put("disabled",  false);
cascadingvalues.put("self",  "https://<url>/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12345");

iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", new ComplexIssueInputFieldValue(cascadingValues));



I have tried these options as well:
    iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("value", "Performance Testing"));

    iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("id", "Performance Testing"));

    iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("value", "12345"));
   

    iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("id", "12345"));

And yet, it throws me the "Option id 'null' is not valid" error. Can someone please help?
Here is the stack trace:
RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={customfield_15870=Option id 'null' is not valid}, errorMessages=[]}]}
       at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
       at com.bla.jira.IssueWriterBeta.createIssue(IssueWriterBeta.java:340)
       at com.bla.almutil.ConnectToJira.createEpic(ConnectToJira.java:282)
       at com.bla.almutil.ConnectToJira.main(ConnectToJira.java:378)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={customfield_15870=Option id 'null' is not valid}, errorMessages=[]}]}
       at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:173)
       at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:167)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:48)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:12)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:295)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:185)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1072)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:161)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:146)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.done(AbstractFuture.java:235)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:172)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:295)
       at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:185)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1072)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:161)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:146)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.done(AbstractFuture.java:235)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:172)
       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
       at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thank you in advance!

The code looks like something you'd be able to step into with a debugger.  Have you tried?  I'm guessing but if you have the exact error message, check the spelling.  Based on what you posted, "Id" and "id" are different strings.

I did, didn't help me much. I can see iib object having the values I injected, but when it reaches Jira it fails with "Option id 'null' is not valid". The "id" and "Id" were typos from me, it is just "id".

Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Done @tgdavies - that's the whole lot I get..

What version of JIRA? And is it Cloud or Enterprise?

Jira v9.5.1 Enterprise

Solved this, I had inadvertently used the same custom field id in a different place that overwrote these values. However, since Java API solutions aren’t found for this elsewhere I’ll anyway post the code for this error:
Map<String, Object> cascadingValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
cascadingvalues.put("value",  "Performance Testing");
cascadingvalues.put("id",  "12345");
iib.setFieldValue("customfield_15870", new ComplexIssueInputFieldValue(cascadingValues));

Just setting the value like other select fields doesn’t cut it for this kind of custom field.
